# Seek second opinion for failed vehicle inspection

Tags: motor-vehicle, maine

I brought my car to a mechanic for an annual state inspection. The mechanic identified a defect which prevented them from passing the car. I brought the vehicle to a different mechanic, disclosed the that the vehicle had just failed, and disclosed the reason for the failure (which I disagreed with). This mechanic inspected the car, and it passed.

Did I commit a crime by seeking a second attempt on state vehicle inspection by a different mechanic? Did the second mechanic commit a crime by passing it, knowing that it just failed somewhere else?

Answer (score 2):

The state inspection laws are [here](https://legislature.maine.gov/statutes/29-A/title29-Ach15sec0.html). The unlawful acts are [here](https://legislature.maine.gov/statutes/29-A/title29-Asec1768.html). Basically, the requirement is that the vehicle be inspected and there is no direct mandate on the vehicle as to how that happens. Only a certified inspector can do it, and the government regulates inspectors. Having conflicting inspection reports is not a crime, nor is having more than one inspection.